# What is a good, HTTP[S] proxy that is customizable in Python?

Tags: networking, proxy, python, web, request

Trying to find a good HTTP proxy that I can customize with Python.  Hopefully, this proxy library or application would allow me to add custom plugins for the request / response cycle - particularly a facility to use another proxy (proxy chaining).  We need to be able to customize the way the custom proxy chooses which proxy server (out of a list) the request will be forwarded with.

Any ideas about where to look?

Thanks very much!